# javascript innerhtml shows as text

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript. And i'm trying to add a div at the top of my `<body>`. But for some reason it adds my code as text like this

[image]

this is my code at the moment.

```
function addDark() {
  document.body.prepend("<div style='position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;background:black;opacity:.9;'></div>")
}
```

How can i fix this problem?
Thanks in advance, Joris

Comment: That would be because you're adding it as text.  Add an element: `var div = document.createElement('div'); div.style.position = 'etc'; document.body.prepend(div);`  Be sure to read the documentation for whatever methods you use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend

Comment: @Help This is vanilla JS, not jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but how would i add a id or class to the div that has been created then?

Comment: @Joris The same way; add it to the div object: `div.id ='id-goes-here'; div.className = 'classes go here';`.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding it like this, and not with ".innerhtml"
Thanks for all the help!

```
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "name";
  div.style.position = "fixed";
  div.style.zIndex = "999";
  document.body.prepend(div);
```

Comment: @Daedalus Fixed my problem

Comment: If your comment is saying that I fixed your problem, I [provided an answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330818/785241).  The above link was only suggested if are unfamiliar with how specific features of this site work.

Comment: oh sorry thanks :) I'm indeed pretty unfamiliar with this site

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an html element being a div. Then you can append your div inside the body element.

```
function addDark() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    // tweak your css for the div here                           
    document.body.prepend(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what browsers you are aiming to have your website support, there are a few ways.

1. The first mentioned way, by [me in a comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330365/javascript-innerhtml-shows-as-text#comment89636491_51330365), is to of course create the div element manually, 
   and append that:

   ```js
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.style.position = 'fixed';
   div.style.top = 0;
   div.innerText = 'more text';
   document.body.prepend(div);
   ```

   Of course, the above way would take awhile to type out, and is thus not really fun.  Here is the documentation link for [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).
2. Then there's [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), mentioned by [Vivek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51330502/785241).  This method isn't preferrable, as it wipes the document body to insert the element.. which unless you're listening to events for in a very specific way, wipes those as well.  I'm not going to get into that way as it is out of scope for this answer.
3. Finally, there is another way; [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).  You can use this method to parse the HTML you write as a string, before inserting in the desired position.  Please refer to the support chart at the bottom of the linked documentation to see if it is supported in your targetted browsers:

   ```js
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.innerHTML = "<div style='position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;background:black;opacity:.9;color:white;'>more text</div>";
   var div = span.querySelector('div');
   document.body.prepend(div);
   ```

Demo of #3:

```js
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = "<div style='position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;background:black;opacity:.9;color:white;'>more text</div>";
var div = span.querySelector('div');
document.body.prepend(div);
```